# Can I ask to rate my English language level?

Tags: feature-request

Can I ask some one to rate the quality of English language by just writing few sentences on any topic?

OR

Can I write some paragraphs on some topic and ask to correct the grammatical mistakes and suggestion for improvisation?

If this above requests cant be done at present. I would request it as a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No! That would be proofreading and evaluation. And, ELL does not entertain such requests.

Various online tests are available to check your English level. You may try one or many of them.

One such test is [here](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/in/test-your-english/). You may google it for more.